# Active state of navbar click persistent after removal JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I update a single html page with new data when clicking `previous` or `next` I am using a `navbar` for the two buttons. However the active, colored state of the navbar click persists even when I remove the class on click with this:

```
$(".nav").removeClass(".ui-btn-active");
```

I have also tried putting this in an `.Click` function. It will work the first time, but on the second click the light blue color of the active state persists. Any recommendations?

Here is the navbar HTML:

```
 <div data-role="navbar" class="nav" >
<ul>
    <!--<li><a href="#" class="ui-btn" onClick="Calendar_Add()" data-icon="calendar"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-icon="mail"></a></li>-->
    <li><a href="#" data-role="button" onClick="previous_event()" data-icon="arrow-l"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-role="button" onClick="next_event()" data-icon="arrow-r"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially remove ui-btn-active class from all tabs

After that on each click remove class ui-btn-active add customize css class you want display.

jQuery:

```
$(".nextLink").click( function() {

 $(".nav").removeClass(".ui-btn-active");

 $(this).addClass("selectedTab");

})
```

CSS:

```
.selectedTab {
background-color: #E4002B !important;

color: #FFFFFF;

font-family: sans-serif;

font-size: 18pt !important;

font-weight: normal;

}
```

**EDIT:**
According to your HTML add and remove Class `onClick` of `previous_event()` & `next_event()`

Comment: I will give this a try tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks!